# .htaccess > 4 urls with same page (will google index all?)

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I have now 4 url's with from the same file:

- http://domain.com/picture.php?name=kim kardashian
- http://domain.com/picture.php?name=kim-kardashian
- http://domain.com/picture/kim kardashian
- http://domain.com/picture/kim-kardashian

All of these links works..

My htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^picture/([^/]*)$ /picture.php?name=$1 [L]
```

In top of my php file (to replace space by -)

```
$name  = str_replace('-', ' ', $_GET['name']);
$name  = mysql_escape_string($name);
$pic = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pics WHERE name = '$name'") or die(mysql_error());
```

But I want to use only: http://domain.com/picture/kim-kardashian, how can I redirect all the other urls to this one using htaccess or php?

And will google index all of these urls or just http://domain.com/picture/kim-kardashian ?

Comment: Google will indexes all of those urls only if some page links them.

Comment: @PierpaoloBagnasco So, if I just use the 4'th url on my website, google won't index the first 3 urls?

Comment: Exactly! Google (or other crawlers) doesn't have knowledge of your files... In this case Google can't know that there is a file/page called pictures.php unless you link it on some page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these rules *before* the one that you have:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ (.*)%20(.*)\ HTTP
RewriteRule . %2-%3 [R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /picture.php\?
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^name=([^&]+)&?(.*)
RewriteRule . /picture/%1?%2 [R=301]
```

The conditions match against `%{THE_REQUEST}` so that we aren't matching against a rewritten URI (like one that your rule rewrites to) and that we are matching against the URI that was actually requested. The first redirects URI's with spaces to replace with a dash (one at a time), and the second looks for requests for `profile.php` and redirects to the SEO friendly version of the URI. After the client gets 301 redirected, your rule will then internally rewrite back to picture.php.

Any links that Google has for the first 3 URIs will eventually get mapped to the 4th because of the 301 redirects.

Comment: Thank you very much!, this worked for me, only buggy is if I the variable: Kim Kardashian Bikini, it will redirect me like this: kim%2520kardashian-bikini. Is there an code to fix that 2?

Comment: @Ibra038 I've added the `NE` flag to the first rule, it prevents the `%` from getting encoded.

Comment: @JohLin, It didn't work, but never mind, im happy with it! Thanks again!